# How to correctly calculate minimum distance with kinematic equations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

Two particles P and Q are initially 40 m apart P behind Q. Particle P starts moving with a uniform velocity 10 m/s towards Q. Particle Q starting from rest has an acceleration $2 m/s^2 $ in the direction of velocity of P. Then the minimum distance between P and Q will be _________.

[image: Problem image]

I used the following method to arrive at the solution:

Assuming time to be 't':

Displacement of P = $10t = s_p$

Displacement of Q : $s_q=(0)t+\frac{1}{2} 2t^2 ==> s_q = t^2$

Separation at time 't' = $s_q-s_p = t^2-10t+c$

At time t=0, $s_q-s_p=40=0^2-10(0)+c => c=40$

Separation at time 't' = $t^2-10t+40 = \Delta S$

Applying maxima minima conditions,

$\frac{dS}{dt} = 2t-10=0 => t=5$

At t=5s, $S_m = 25-50+40 = 15m$

Applying second derivative test also I get my answer verified. But actual answer is given as 30.

Where did I go wrong? Also is there any alternate method?

Edited to cater to an answer given.

Comment: Check my profile to have an idea of my level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your answer is correct.

An alternative approach, without calculus, is to note that the minimum separation will occur when the velocity of Q equals the constant velocity of P - up until this time, P is catching up with Q; from this time onwards Q is pulling away from P. P and Q have equal velocities at $t=5$ seconds, at which time P has travelled $50$ metres from its initial position and Q has  travelled half as far, $25$ metres. Taking into account the initial separation of $40$ metres between P and Q, we find that the minimum distance between P and Q is $40 + 25 - 50 = 15$ metres.